# Issues on sandbox refreshing

Tags: apex

After refreshing sandbox or creating new sandbox all real time data should be replace in sandbox. So after QA perform any test the email should sent to live email Id. I want all the object(custom and Standard) in org that have Email data type field and append some text to all the records so email not sent to real address?
How to do that or please suggest any other way to prevent that.

Comment: You can write batch job, that will take as parameter list of sObjects, where emails fields should be replaced. Start method should return selector for all records, Then in execute you call describe, find all fields with type email, update them. in finish, chain batch for another sobject in the list, that is still unprocessed

Comment: Or just turn off email deliverability if it does not affect the testing.

Comment: Email deliverability is the option that I though but it will stop all  the email including system and all workflow etc..

Comment: @Ravi - you can set it to system email only. As for code there is no easy code. You would have to write code for every object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes under activities which we can name as de-prod.

You have to create a Batchable class which will query you object data with email field values and you need to mask that data with some random keyword or sandbox name.

e.g. email field value = abc@company.com

you can mask it as - abc@company.com.sandboxname

And you have to run/ schedule batch jobs to mask emails.

***Example***

```
global class MaskEmail implements Database.Batchable{

    String objectName;
    String notifyEmail = 'notify@notifyme.com';
    String sandboxName;
    global MaskEmail (String sandboxName, String objectName){
        this.objectName = objectName;
        this.sandboxName = sandboxName;
    }                        

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String query;

        if (objectName == 'Case') {
            query = 'Select id, SuppliedEmail FRom Case';
        }
        else if (objectName == 'Contact') {
            query = 'Select id, Email FROM Contact'; 

        } 
        else if(objectName == 'User'){
            query = 'Select id, Email FROM USER';

        }

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }


    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List listSObject){    
        if (objectName == 'Contact') {  
            List<Contact> list_Contact = (List<Contact>) listSObject; 
            for(Contact tempContact: list_Contact){
                tempContact.Email = tempContact.Email + '.' +sandboxName;
            }               
            update list_Contact;     
        } 

        else if (objectName == 'User') {  
            List<User> list_User = (List<User>) listSObject; 
            integer i=1;
            for(User tempUser: list_User){
                    tempUser.Email = tempUser.Email + '.' +sandboxName;
            }               
            update list_User;     
        }
        else if(objectName == 'Case'){
            List<Case> list_Case = (List<Case>) listSObject;
            for(Case tempCase: list_Case){
                tempCase.SuppliedEmail =  tempCase.SuppliedEmail + '.' +sandboxName;
            }
            update list_Case;
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String body = 'Job Finished at :'+DateTime.Now();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage tempMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {notifyEmail};
        tempMail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        tempMail.setSubject('Mask Email status for '+objectName+' in '+sandboxName);
        tempMail.setPlainTextBody(body);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { tempMail });

    }
}
```

***Run Batch Apex From the Developer Console***
1. Click Debug | then Open Execute Anonymous Window.
2. Execute the following  code.

For Case's Email Mask:

```
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new MaskEmail('TestSandbox','Case'), 200);
```

For Contact's Email Mask:

```
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new MaskEmail('TestSandbox','Contact'), 200);
```

For User's Email Mask:

```
Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new MaskEmail('TestSandbox','User'), 200);
```

Comment: Better set email deliverability to 'System Only'/ 'None' so that change of user's email won't trigger warning to original user or any case update notifications wont trigger to contact emails

Comment: thank you...but hear we need to run this batch class manually for every object.Is there any way to make it dynamically to run for all object in org.